# Error: Failed to resolve: com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:1.6.5

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx, lwjgl

I used gdx-setup.jar to generate a gradle project and then imported it inside Android Studio.  But when I try to compile it, I get this error.

I checked the "desktop" + "Android" option while generating and use Android API 20.  When I navigated inside the project, I found that in the DesktopLauncher.java class LwjglApplicationConfiguration appears red.  The import statements

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
```

are both marked with errors.  "lwjgl" is red and upon hovering over shows "Couldn't resolve symbol 'lwjgl' in blah blah"

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed.

For some strange reason, the gdx-setup.jar file was not downloading lwjgl jar files into the .gradle folder in C:\Users\.  Not sure why this was happening, maybe a bug.  I went to Advanced settings and checked "IDEA" and then clicked generate.  This time it downloaded a whole load of jar files.  After it finished, I regenerated again by unchecking "IDEA" so that I would get a Gradle based build.

Finally it works.  Maybe there's a bug in gdx-setup.jar

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after updating. However, all I did was click build, then rebuild project, wait for it to rebuild and then for gradle to sync. After that everything should be fine.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work.  On rebuilding, it finishes with 1 warning. warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
I then went to Tools -> Android -> Sync but it fails again with "couldn't resolve lwjgl"

Comment: Is there a reason why you use Android API 20, when it says "You have newer version than recommended", click yes both times, does your problem still exist after that?

Comment: Tried by clicking Yes twice but still the same error.  The reason I am targeting API 20 is that I want my App to be compatible with it.  If I target 23 which is Android M, my app won't be compatible with other lower version android devices.  The error is not occurring in the android folder, its happening in the Desktop version of the class in "DesktopLauncher.java".  So android API doesn't seem to be the issue.